# Use getDefaultSharedPreferences before user opens settings activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a [Settings Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) in my Android app. The settings have default values in `res/xml/preferences.xml`. The problem I'm having is that until the user actually goes into the settings page, the default preferences are not saved and I cannot retrieve the default values stored in the XML file.

The code:

#### res/xml/preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="xml default value"
        android:title="foo"
        android:summary="bar"
        android:key="mykey" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

#### SettingsActivity.java

```
package bh.gov.cio.gdt.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Inside another activity:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String myvalue = settings.getString("mykey", "code default value")
Log.d(LOG_TAG, myvalue);
```

The call to `settings.getString` returns `"code default value"` when the application is first installed. But once the user opens the Settings activity at least once, it returns `xml default value`.

I want to avoid forcing the user to go to the settings page when the program is run for the first time. I also want to avoid harcoding the default values twice, in the XML file and in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to call in your activity `OnCreate()`

`PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.advanced_preferences, false);`